# Could not find default endpoint element that references contract (simple WCF Service not working)

Tags: c#, wcf

The full error message:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'SampleProject.ITextMessage' in the ServiceModel client configuration
>   section. This might be because no configuration file was found for
>   your application, or because no endpoint element matching this
>   contract could be found in the client element.

This is a console app. Can't get much simpler from this.

**No app config desired in this case**, just looking to get a simple sample going.  I pretty much lifted the code from here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx

Any help would be appreciated.

```
   public class SampleProject
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var baseAddr = new Uri("http://localhost:6000/TextMessageSvc.svc");

            using (var localHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(TextMessageClient), baseAddr))
            {
                try
                {
                    //THIS page says an endpoint is not needed, a default will be created automatically:
                    //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx
                    localHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITextMessage),
                                                 new WSHttpBinding(),
                                                 "TextMessageSvc");

                    var behavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                    behavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                    behavior.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;

                    localHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
                    localHost.Open();

                    Console.WriteLine("Service initialized.");

                    //************** Blows up on this line ***********************
                    var x = new TextMessageClient();
                    x.SendTextMessage();

                    Console.WriteLine("Press the ENTER key to terminate service.");
                    Console.ReadLine();

                    localHost.Close();
                }
                catch (CommunicationException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Oops! Exception: {0}", ex.Message);
                    localHost.Abort();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class TextMessageClient : ClientBase<ITextMessage>, ITextMessage
    {
        public void SendTextMessage()
        {
            base.Channel.SendTextMessage();
        }
    }

    [ServiceBehavior]
    public class TextMessageSvc : ITextMessage
    {
        public TextMessageSvc()
        {

        }

        [OperationBehavior]
        public void SendTextMessage()
        {

        }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITextMessage
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void SendTextMessage();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that the issue in this example is (since I'm not using a web config), that TextMessageClient does not have **an endpoint**. (localhost has one, but not *TextMessageClient*) When I call SendTextMessage, how is it going to communicate? Who is it going to talk to??

Well heck, I could create an endpoint and pass it into TextMessageClient, or just create one in its constructor, which I am now doing.

So after a renaming of TextMessageSvc to TextMessageProxy and then a refactor. **This is all I now need** (If you notice the new code is only *consuming* a service now, rather than attempting to *host* one as well:

I now have a function somewhere that sets up an endpoint for TextMessageClient to use.

```
var uri = _appSettings.Get("FredServiceURI");  //"http://localhost:3333/FredService.svc/"
var wcfSendTextMessage = new TextMessageProxy(uri);
```

The TextMessage class now provides its own endpoint:

```
   public class TextMessageProxy : ClientBase<IFredContract>, IFredContract
    {
        public TextMessageProxy(string url, WebHttpSecurityMode securityMode = WebHttpSecurityMode.None)
            : base(ConstructEndpoint(url, securityMode))
        {
        }

        public string SendTextMessage(string sendToPhoneNumber, string messageText)
        {
            return base.Channel.SendTextMessage(sendToPhoneNumber, messageText);
        }

        // This method constructs a WebHttpBinding endpoint with all the appropriate
        // settings for talking to our services.
        private static ServiceEndpoint ConstructEndpoint(string serviceUri, WebHttpSecurityMode securityMode)
        {
            var contract = ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IFredContract));
            var binding = new WebHttpBinding(securityMode);

            var address = new EndpointAddress(serviceUri);
            var endpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(
                contract,
                binding,
                address);

            //custom stuff.  You may or may not need these settings, but I do.. 
            //I would think you need at least the behavior, as it is likely required, as it is in the web.config.
            //-------------
            var webHttpBehavior = new WebHttpBehavior()
            {
                FaultExceptionEnabled = true
            };

            endpoint.Behaviors.Add(webHttpBehavior);
            //-------------

            return endpoint;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your base address is specifying a service page (TextMessageSvc.svc), so I doubt it's valid for a base address.  So when you add the endpoint, you're getting something like this:

```
`http://localhost:6000/TextMessageSvc/TestMessage.svc/extMesssageSvc")`
```

Try this:

```
var baseAddr = new Uri("http://localhost:6000/TextMessageSvc");
```

Also, be aware that default endpoints (as you seem to be using them) are a feature of WCF 4.0 (.NET 4.0/VS 2010), and not available in previous versions.